# Why does PowerShell code behave different when called from a function?

Tags: powershell

Experienced C# developer learning PowerShell here so I am sure I am just missing something silly. What I am trying to do is write a function that simply writes it's input to a temporary file in JSON format. I have code that works fine if I run it 'inline', but that same code writes an empty file when called in a function.

Here is the code:

```
function Dump-File {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $Input
    )
    $tmp = New-TemporaryFile
    $Input | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File $tmp.FullName 
    Write-Output "Dump file written: $($tmp.FullName)"
}

$args = @{}
$args.Add('a', 1)
$args.Add('b', 2)
$args.Add('c', 3)
$args.Add('d', 4)

# results in json written to temp file
$tmp = New-TemporaryFile
$args | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File $tmp.FullName
Write-Output "args dumped: $($tmp.FullName)"

# results in empty temp file
Dump-File $args
```

Can anyone help me understand why the code called inline works but the same code does not work when I wrap it up as a function?

Comment: $Input is a reserved keyword in Powershell. Change your parameter name to anything else.

Comment: It's good to look at the names of parameters of the built-in PS cmdlets and apply the same pattern to your own. You will see those similar to yours all have the parameter called `InputObject`. Also, it's good to look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands, so your function should be named something like `Out-...` (And you might consider making it a fully functional cmdlet with `[CmdletBinding()]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$Input` is an automatic variable.

Changing the name of your **Dump-File** parameter to `$somethingelse` will resolve your problem. Never use `$input` as a parameter or variable name.

Automatic variables are to be considered read-only.

> **About Automatic Variables**
>
> **SHORT DESCRIPTION**
>
> Describes variables that store state information for
>   PowerShell. These variables are created and maintained by PowerShell.
>
> **LONG DESCRIPTION**
>
> Conceptually, these variables are considered to be
>   read-only. Even though they can be written to, for backward
>   compatibility they should not be written to.
>
> Here is a list of the automatic variables in PowerShell:
>
> ...
>
> **$INPUT**
>
> Contains an enumerator that enumerates all input that is passed to a function. The $input variable is available only to functions and script blocks (which are unnamed functions). In the Process block of a function, the $input variable enumerates the object that is currently in the pipeline. When the Process block completes, there are no objects left in the pipeline, so the $input variable enumerates an empty collection. If the function does not have a Process block, then in the End block, the $input variable enumerates the collection of all input to the function.

Source: [About_Automatic_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1)

This information is also avaible through `Get-help` command

`Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables`

Comment: Yeah - I can see how that would be a problem then. I think that may explain some other weirdness I experienced earlier then. Thanks Sage!